# Live Connect API for fetching Client ID

Tags: oauth-2.0

In the Facebook API, there is a request that provides details about the application that a particular OAuth access token is for. For example, I could send

```
http://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=ABC...123
```

and it would return information about the application that the access token was generated for. It has a very similar one to get information about the user the access token was generated for.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ABC...123
```

My question pertains to the parallel calls in Microsoft's Live Connect RESTful API. There is a direct equivalent to the `/me` request that returns the user's unique ID, but I cannot find any documentation for a parallel to the `/app` request (client in MS terminology).

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=ABC...123
{
   "id": "1234abc1a1abc123", 
   "name": "test test", 
   "first_name": "test", 
   "last_name": "test", 
   "gender": null, 
   "locale": "en_US"
}

https://apis.live.net/v5.0/app?access_token=ABC...123
{
   "error": {
      "code": "request_url_invalid", 
      "message": "The URL contains the path 'app', which isn't supported."
   }
}

https://apis.live.net/v5.0/client?access_token=ABC...123
{
   "error": {
      "code": "request_url_invalid", 
      "message": "The URL contains the path 'client', which isn't supported."
   }
}
```

Comment: Try looking through MS documentation, just because Facebook has it, doesn't necessarily mean it's going to be there in MS.

Comment: @phwd I did check the REST API like I mentioned in the post. Just wasn't sure if it was called something funny that I wouldn't recognize and thought someone who works with LiveConnect more routinely might know off the top of their head.